# When do you use "by" to signal a time period

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which version is correct?

"You will receive this information tomorrow" or "You will receive this information by tomorrow"

Comment: Is it possible that he'll receive the information before tomorrow? Use *by*. Is it known that he will definitely get the information tomorrow, not sooner, not later? Don't use *by*. For more details on the reasons and contexts we use prepositions in English, please use our sister site, [ELL.se].

Answer (score 1):

"You will receive this information tomorrow" connotes that the information will be received tomorrow, neither before nor after.

"You will receive this information by tomorrow", on the other hand, states that the information may be received before tomorrow.

In answer to the question, both are 'correct'.